# System.Core.dll in 4.0 added by default?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I was playing around with VS2010 beta2. I noticed that if I try to add System.Core.dll to a project which does not already have a reference to that, in VS2010, it complains saying I cannot add that assembly as it is already referenced by the project system. Any idea why they are doing that in VS2010/4.0? Is it because they have forwarded few types to mscorlib from System.Core?

Comment: Thanks for this question, we tried .Net4 with vs2010, but our solution had too much baggage that wouldn't work so we moved back to 3.5. Following the bug you raised, I found the workaround so that I could add the reference to System.Core back into a project that wouldn't build without it.

Comment: Faced same issue in VS2012 when porting SL4 project to SL5.

Answer (score 5):

Not an answer for "why they are doing that", but could be helpful.

This is how I see the chain of actions that lead to implicit referencing `System.Core.dll`:

- You make a project in Visual Studio 2010. It generates .csproj with
  `ToolsVersion=4.0`. Suppose it will use MSBuild from .NET 4.
- Your .csproj imports `Microsoft.CSharp.targets` from `$(MSBuildBinPath)`. I guess it will be `c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.CSharp.targets`
- Microsoft.CSharp.targets imports `Microsoft.Common.targets`
- In .NET 4, Microsoft.Common.targets imports `Microsoft.NETFramework.props`
- In Microsoft.NETFramework.props you can find `AdditionalExplicitAssemblyReferences` node, which has a semicolon-separated list of assemblies. I found there System.Core.dll and a variable for later replacement.

So, to **disable implicit reference** of System.Core.dll, you can remove it from the list in `AdditionalExplicitAssemblyReferences` node in `c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.NETFramework.props`.

After this, if you use, for example, `System.Linq` and have no reference to System.Core.dll in your project, you will logically get compile error, just like in Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 3):

System.Core has been part of the required framework since 3.5, because it includes things like ExtensionAttribute and the LINQ Standard Query Operators.  Similarly, if you create a 3.5 project in VS2008, it will automatically add a reference to System.Core for you.

Comment: I know it adds reference to System.Core by default even in 3.5. But the difference here is, if you remove that reference of System.Core from the project, then try to add it back, it will crib saying that the assembly is already to the project. This does not happen in 3.5.

Comment: That sounds like a bug: either it should not let you remove this required reference, or it should let you add it back if you do remove the reference.  May be worth reporting on Connect.

Comment: Bug raised: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=525663