# Where does csc get its default list of libraries?

Tags: c#, .net

The C# compiler requires some libraries to be referenced with `-r` options if you want to use them, but by default it goes ahead and references several of the most commonly used .Net libraries.

Where does it get the list of libraries to reference by default? I have seen it mentioned that it's a configuration file somewhere, but cannot now find any reference to that file.

If it makes a difference, I'm talking purely about the command line compiler, csc.exe, not about the IDE.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS2017 C# default assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55072426/vs2017-c-sharp-default-assemblies)

Comment: @OlivierRogier The GAC is unrelated here. The compiler will search the GAC if an assembly is passed with `-r`, but the question is about which assemblies are referenced *without needing `-r`*

Comment: @canton7 Yes, thank you! The relevant file is csc.rsp